# Confusing about the correct Logistic (Verhulst) equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've seen on journal that logistic is derived from exponential by putting $k=r(M-P)$ on $$\frac{\Bbb dP}{\Bbb dt} = kP$$ and we get the following logistic equation
$$\frac{\Bbb dP}{\Bbb dt} = r(M-P)P \tag{1}$$

But, then i got the different formula on youtube. With 2 variables and 3 variables on the RHS.

$$\frac{\Bbb dP}{\Bbb dt} = KP\left(1-\frac PK\right)\tag{2}$$

$$\frac{\Bbb dP}{\Bbb dt} = KP\left(1-\frac PM\right)\tag{3}$$

So, which one is true and what is your reference? Help. Or explain to me if actually all of them are true but just have different variables. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is more restrictive, you can multiply it out to get
$$
\frac{dP}{dt}=P(K-P)
$$
If you allow time scaling, all the equations are equivalent.

Instead of making the reproduction rate variable, you could also see the logistic equation as having an additional competition term that simulates that if individuals come close too often, then it reduces the overall life span, $2P\overset{r}\to P+D$, $D=$ deceased, while $P\overset{rM}\to2P$ covers the births.